# IIS - How can i put my website on the internet?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, web-hosting, windows-server-2012

I'm with some doubts concerning on the publication of my website on the internet.
I searched a lot on the internet but i can't find answers. Maybe i'm making the wrong questions, but i will post here my doubts so anyone can help me and anothers with same issues.

I have a local network. This local network has a main computer (Windows Server) with some Websites. 
This websites are working in the local network. Now i want to put them on the internet, how can i do that?
Can i use my windows server to host the site? 
How can i get a domain and point this domain to my server-pc ip?

Comment: “How can i get a domain” is not a programming question at all. If you use a search engine, there are tons of domain name providers. Even if you don't want to buy a domain yet, you can modify hosts file to emulate.

Comment: @LexLi probably you didn't read all the question. The question is "How can i get a domain and point this domain to my server-pc ip?". The question is about the configuration of IIS. If you can help me I appreciate it. Many Thanks.

Comment: No. That requires almost zero IIS configuration as the default site already uses a catch-all site binding, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background All you need is networking related, such as a valid domain name, correct DNS records, and other settings on the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i want to put them on the internet, how can i do that?

Firslty, you need a public IP address to let the internet user to access your server. Then you should register a domain and bind the domain with the pubic IP address.

After  doing this, you could set the IIS site binding with the domain you have registered to let the customer to access your site.

> Can i use my windows server to host the site?

Yes

> How can i get a domain and point this domain to my server-pc ip?

You need to contact to your network provider to buy a public IP address. Then you need to buy a domain on the domain provider like GoDaddy. Then you could follow the domain provider's article to set DNS(bind with public IP).